# Image not center after adding anchor

Tags: html, css

Im making a portfolio website for school and id like to make the first image in the slideshow clickable but when I wrap an anchor around it the image goes from center to the bottom right of the screen.

```
<div class="col-12 p-0 m-0">
                    <div class="slideshow">
                        <div class="programming-slides">
                            <a href="home.html"><img src="images/mlspprojectimage.png"     alt="Machine Learning Stock Picker"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="programming-slides">
                            <img src="images/AdobeStock_231690594.jpeg" alt="image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

.business-slides img, .programming-slides img, .webdesign-slides img, .architecture-slides  img       {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.business-slides a, .programming-slides a, .webdesign-slides a, .architecture-slides a {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

slideshow {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a flexbox?

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your slideshow className wasn't .slideshow

```css
.business-slides img, .programming-slides img, .webdesign-slides img, .architecture-slides  img       {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.business-slides a, .programming-slides a, .webdesign-slides a, .architecture-slides a {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 70vh;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.slideshow {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 p-0 m-0">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="programming-slides">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCA5N3QZN5XlgXqbsDDDJXBv6QizwUs3YuQX5QWtsTZIquainPKEGmnqcbPCdNpapoegg&usqp=CAU"     
        alt="Machine Learning Stock Picker">
       </a>
     </div>
    <div class="programming-slides">
     <a href="/">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9n7nTgLX7gD4EchFzaoC_Wx_rg6xjn11ityF0gKhMXH4wxlGVa4dXYF9tsdKM3Xh1BAA&usqp=CAU" 
      alt="image">
      </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing position to relative instead of absolute.